# Fetching & Self-hosting an XML Feed

Tags: xml, ftp, feed, fetch

I have a situation whereby a company is providing me an xml file with the following restrictions:

1. Username/Password protected
2. Stored on their ftp
3. I'm not allowed to reference the file from my application

So I was hoping to come up with something to fetch the xml file every hour (as their file is updated hourly), and host it on my own domain.

Would anyone have any suggestions about creating something like this, or is there any existing scripts that might do it for me?

Many thanks,
Glen

Comment: Which language (PHP, .NET c#, etc) /?  ... and how big is the file?

Comment: I think we're using a windows server - .NET capable, but php is also enabled.  Probably prefer PHP as I can read it :)  File is tiny - under 5kb

Comment: Just wondering did my answer help?

Comment: Sure did!  I am receiving a text encoding error.. but i think this is due to the xml rather than the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple bit of PHP to cache the remote file and serve up the local copy.

Based on this [PHP Remote File Cache](http://snipplr.com/view/14795/php-remote-file-cache/) example you could do something like this (untested):

```
<?php
$url = 'ftp://username:password@server.domain.com/folder/file.ext';
#we need to do some caching here
$cache_dir = dirname(__FILE__) . '/cache/'; // directory to store the cache
$cache_file = $cache_dir . md5($url);
$cache_time = 1 * 60 * 60; // time to cache file, # minutes * seconds

// check the cache_dir variable
if (is_dir($cache_dir) && 
    is_writable($cache_dir) && 
    file_exists($cache_file) && 
    (time() - $cache_time) < filemtime($cache_file)) {
    $data = file_get_contents($cache_file); // name of the cached file
}
else {
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    file_put_contents($cache_file, $data); //go ahead and cache the file
}


// Compress output if we can.
if (function_exists('ob_gzhandler')) {
    ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
}


header('Content-type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8'); // Change this as needed
// think about client side caching...
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + $cache_time) . ' GMT');
echo $data;
exit;
```